# Unable to access any kind of Terminal( terminal, uxterm, xterm, Guake terminal...) on my PC

Tags: command-line, user-profile

As soon as I open the terminal it gets closes automatically. I think the problem is due to some change in ~/.profile, because the file got modified when I was installing some software.

I am able to run terminal in guest session but then, sudo doesn't works there.

Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: You can move or delete .bashrc and .profile from file manager. There's root recovery terminal, theres also an option to run gnome terminal with dash....i think ill post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

**Troubleshooting option #1**

Open file manager, enable viewing hidden files, remove `.bashrc` and `.profile` or move them to another location other than your home directory.

**Troubleshooting option #2**

Access terminal via <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> and run `gnome-terminal -e dash`, which will open gnome-terminal with  Debian Amquist Shell (dash) instead of Bourne Again Shell (bash).

[image]

**Troubleshooting option #3**

When booting a computer, get to OS selection screen (commonly know as grub, you may need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> button several times before computer shows purple screen). From there select Advanced options for Ubuntu -> Ubuntu with kernel 3.xx (recovery ) -> root shell

You will need to remount file system with `mount / -o remount,rw` to be able to make any changes to files on the disk.

**Troubleshooting option #4**

Go to System Settings -> User Accounts. Create another admin user. Log in as that new admin user and open terminal. Navigate to your  home folder, run `sudo chown newusername:newusername .bashrc .profile`. Once you delete those files or edit them, run `chown` and change ownership back to your old username.

[image]